# Ad By: MediaPlayer

Tags: malware, popup-ads

Help! I'm getting popups and ads all over the place and they all say "Ad By: MediaPlayer".

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm fairly new to ubuntu 14.04 and thought that viruses were virtually impossible to get with Linux but it seems as though I have one that I very much want to get rid of. What do I do?

Comment: can you take a screen-shot and put it on http://imgur.com/ - then paste a link here.

Comment: Sounds like you are browsing web sites which provide such ads, or you have installed a browser extension which does so.

Comment: I get these on most websites that I visit.
http://imgur.com/nrpR3ER
http://imgur.com/O4O9RpW
http://imgur.com/mrLt7jM

Comment: Close Firefox and move `~/.mozilla` (which contains your firefox profile) to a new name. I also suggest trying various ad-blockers, which are useful anyway: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/?src=search https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/?src=ss https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/?src=search . Only install extensions from https://addons.mozilla.org

Comment: Sounds similar to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/600396)

Comment: Does this happen with other browsers too (e. g. Epiphany, Chromium, or Chrome)? Do they appear in safe mode as well (for Firefox: close the browser, open a terminal and run `firefox -safe-mode`)? Which add-ons and plug-ins do you have in your browser? Do any of them look unknown or suspicious? If you're unsure, post their names or a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a extension in the Firefox Bowser.
If it's this jus go to Firefox Bowser -> On the top right you have the menu icon with three lines pres and go to Complements then go to extensions and delete the extension from there.

Hope I helpped you ^^"