# An adware has infected 2 browsers

Tags: firefox, chromium, malware, popup-ads

A weird adware is popping up every time I open a .com website and shows ad or redirects the page.
In chrome, I'm not even able to open an ordinary .com page because it immediately redirects to somewhere else.

I've reset Firefox, even purged and reinstalled it but the problem's not solved.
This is one screenshot of mine, you see the adware at bottom-right corner.
I'm using Kubuntu 14.04 with firefox 36.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the extensions and add-on that you are using?

Comment: extensions: Ubuntu Firefox Modifications and add-ons: shokwave flash, open264 video codec and skype buttons for kopete

Comment: Other addons, plugins, ecc? It's maybe better if you post the screenshots of these configurations.

Comment: I've added more screenshots

Comment: Have you made any changes to DNS settings? How do you connect to the Internet? Does this happen everywhere you use your computer? (if it's a laptop, obviously it's not portable if it's a desktop)

Comment: @MohsenNowrouzi what your settings for the DNS servers?

Comment: please in firefox go to preferences - advanced - network - connection - settings - and show your proxy settings, if possible try to select "none"  http://i.stack.imgur.com/oeNUo.png

Comment: I'm not using proxy ( sometimes i do but not at this moment). My DNS settings is what my ISP provided and i didn't change it.

Comment: @MohsenNowrouzi try to change the DNS, set them to OpenDNS or Google DNS and see if that solves the problem. It may happen that the problem is on your ISP's DNS server side.

Comment: please verify that proxy is selected "none" it is a known way to hijack pages...

Comment: I have another Linux installed on my system. It has affected  while i haven't used it for awhile. I changed my DNS but didn't work. I'm not using proxy at the moment, we have a windows system at home too, it is Ok, so maybe something is running in the background and ruined my system.

Comment: I've come accross another case where a router was infected, and was affecting all browsers on all computers in a persons house. I suggest you go and check router settings there, especially dns, and set admin password so that malicious users cant get back into the router.

Comment: Start FF in "safe mode" too

Comment: Shockwave Flash is very old and insecure besides being almost useless these days. I suggest uninstalling it.

Answer (score 5):

1.
Maybe try to remove your personal files (or backup them first if you need to). They are located in:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox
~/.config/google-chrome
```

and some caches:

```
~/.cache/mozilla/firefox
~/.cache/google-chrome
```

Both of these browsers will create new profiles for you at first run.

---

2.
You can also examine system-wide addons, they are at:

```
/usr/share/mozilla
/usr/lib/mozilla  
/usr/lib/chromium-browser
```

---

3.
If its not the addons that couses problems, it also can be [Man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack - something is changing HTML/JavaScript on the arrival - check your proxy settings, your routing tables, your internet gateway... Check network requests in "Developer Tools" in those browsers (Firefox: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). Download some .html in terminal (`wget <url>`), check if its changed.

Comment: Didn't help. why is it infecting both firefox and chromium? Has it infected my OS? Is it possible?

Comment: One workaround for my problem is to use https for all websites, but it's not always possible.

Comment: Of course it can be in your system. Not changing https (encrypted) pages is sort of a proof, that this malware modifies content of the pages (unencrypted).

Answer (score 3):

Thank all for responses.
I installed "clamav" and ran a full scan on my system; Unfortunately I forgot to tell it to save scan log, I thought it  would do it itself; anyway, my problem solved and I don't know what was the real cause.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably check your running processes. See how [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/).

Try [Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) (this wont solve the problem but at least may stop your ads). Install clamav and rkhunter.

If I were you, I would, personally, reinstall the OS, there is allways a new ubuntu version comming up.

Comment: An antivirus for Linux? Re-installing whole OS due to infection? These don't sound good. It reminds me MS Windows.

Comment: All systems Linux or not are vulnerable to malware. Yours is the proof, but it happens specially if you dont protect it well. Everybody should take this course: https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/introduction-to-cyber-security it's free, easy, and funny.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a wild guess, but what is your home router DNS settings?  As an experiment, change your system DNS resolver to f.e. [Verisign Public DNS](https://www.verisign.com/en_US/innovation/public-dns/index.xhtml) - (64.6.64.6) or [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) (8.8.8.8) and see whether this changes your experience.

If yes, then throw your home router to trash, as there are many security bugs in home routers and exploits are running wild.  Buy something more decent that receives updates or OpenWRT/LEDE can be installed there ([Turris Omnia](https://omnia.turris.cz/en/) might be a good option).

Answer (score 1):

As a safety measure **Install [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb)** on your both of the browsers. Once install ,it will ask you to turn on the features that you want (it will be the page where they will request you for donation , scroll down to see the options ). Turn on all of the options for safe and add free browsing.

Answer (score 1):

For me to stop the popups in chrome i went to `settings -> Privacy and security - > Site Settings - > Notifications` and the site that was sending me all the popups was in the `Allow` section , then press on the 3 dots and choose "remove"

I had popups saying "Your norton is expired"

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with firefox, I tried every malware and virus program know to man without any luck and uninstalled /reinstalled firefox many times. Then I was reading a blog on a related page and it mentioned the firefox folder, I took a chance and deleted the whole firefox folder and reinstalled firefox restarted the computer, restarted firefox and now no more adds.

I hope this helps others as much as it did me, I was at wits end!

Comment: Put link of that blog in your answer, it would be helpful for OP

Answer (score 0):

Try removing firefox and chrome from your system and removing all settings and config of these two apps by executing following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox google-chrome --purge && rm -rf ~/.mozilla ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.local/share/applications/chrome* ~/.cache/google-chrome ~/.cache/mozilla ~/.config/chromium ~/.cache/chromium /opt/google/chrome && sudo rm -rf /usr/share/mozilla /usr/lib/mozilla /usr/lib/chromium-browser /etc/chromium /etc/firefox
```

Then reinstall firefox and chrome by executing following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install firefox google-chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

On all your browsers go to clear browsing data in menu->settings from the beginning to present, tick all boxes and go. you will be out of problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are browsers other than Firefox and chromium that block malware and popup-ads and additionally, block trackers, fingerprinting and third party cookies. The Brave browser does this. check out brave at  https://brave.com/
You can download brave on Ubuntu by using the `Sudo apt install brave` or the Debian command `sudo apt-get install brave`